# Cardinality of index in MySQL and foreign key id insertion

Tags: php, sql

1. i have two tables where 
   **customer table**
   **customer_id(pk)**,fullname,matric_id,ic_no,gender,address,postcode,state,hp_number,tel_number,username,password,repeatpassword.

   **booktickect table**
   **ticket_id(pk)**,*customer_id(fk)*,liner,direction,from,f_date,f_time,destination,t_date,t_time,total_price
2. actually i have inserted 8 data in the customer table,hence it shows
   8 as the cardinality of my primary key(customer_id).But why when i
   take a look at my foreign key(customer_id),its cardinality is
   showing 0 instead of 8.
3. and another thing is in the sql database where there is an option of
   inserting values.my values for the foreign key has been updated to
   the 8 id's from the customer table.hence i think this shows that the
   foreign key is working but if i want to insert data into the
   database,i can't do so.tq in advance

Comment: In PHPMyAdmin, "cardinality" is the "number of unique values" for that column.  If your bookticket table is empty, the `bookticket.customer_id` column will have cardinality of zero.

Comment: The dropdown for the foreign key fetches values from the referenced customer table.  The cardinality for `customer_id` in the `bookticket` table is the number of unique values for `customer_id` in the `bookticket` table.

Comment: tq @Andomar.another thing is when i open the insert option in the phpmyadmin,i can see the values of the foreign key(customer_id)in the bookticket table which is inherited from the other table(customer).in my php, i can also get the customer_id for the current session `echo $_SESSION['customer_id'];` but when i want to insert into database ,the values is not being inserted into the table.this is my code `$customer_id=mysql_insert_id();
$query="INSERT INTO bookticket VALUES('','$customer_id','$liner','$direction','$from','$f_date','$f_time','$destination','$t_date','$t_time','$total_price')";`

Comment: Be sure to [check MySQL errors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4125792/50552) with `mysql_error()`.  From a quick glance, you typically can't enter `''` as your primary key.  It's either an auto-increment column (in which case you should omit it from the `insert` entirely) or it's your job to enter a unique value there.

Comment: Thank You Mr.@Andomar .By default i have set the primary key to auto increment.and that `' '`   quote that i did is because i follow it from a video tutorial where they implement an empty single quoted space for auto incremented primary key