# Unable to insert data in a table using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have this following code->

html5 code  block:

```
<div class="col-md-8 blogger-right-container">
                <form action="blogger_account.php" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h2>Blog Title</h2>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="blog_title" placeholder="Enter title for your blog.">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h2>Blog Content</h2>
                        <textarea name="blog_content" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Enter the content here."></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="add" value="Insert">
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div> <!-- blogger right container -->
```

php code block: 
`

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){

    $blogger = $_SESSION['blogger_email'];
    $blog_title = $_POST['blog_title'];
    $blog_content = $_POST['blog_content'];

    $insert_blog = "insert into blogs (blogger_email,blog_title,blog_content) values ('$blogger',$blog_title','$blog_content')";

    $run_blog = mysqli_query($con,$insert_blog);

    if($run_blog){
    echo "<script>alert('Blog inserted.')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('blogger_account.php','_self')</script>";
    }

}`
```

The php code block is not inserting the data in blogs table. The columns are in proper order, but still i tried to change the sequence and it didn't worked.
Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code.

Comment: @session_start is missing?

Comment: session_start is given in the starting of html document. Still it isn't working

Comment: -there is some errors in your code.please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please mention Error you are receiving.

In order to show detailed php errors, navigate to " [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) "

MySQL errors in php can be thrown this way --> [PHP MySQL error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125559/php-mysql-error-handling)

Comment: In order to show detailed php errors, navigate to " How to get useful error messages in PHP? "

MySQL errors in php can be thrown this way --> PHP MySQL error handling